# javaservlet page

Tags: jsp, forms

Can I submit a jsp form without using submit button but with a link? if possible how ?
Please let me know as soon as possible. I am stuck with my project.

Comment: You question turns out to be ambiguous. Do you want to send some input field values along with the link?

Answer (score 1):

Sure ... you can do something like below:-

```
<form id="test" action="something">
    <a href="javascript: submitform()">Submit Form</a>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitform()
    {
      document.getElementById('test').submit();
    }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can. Just let the link URL point to an URL matching the servlet's `<url-pattern>` and then do the job in `doGet()` method of the servlet.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 0):

Only submit buttons can really submit the form on their own.

Forms can only be submitted by links if the links have an javascript onclick event that submits the form. Another option is to use a special class attribute on the submit button to make it look like a link with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

You can use javascript to submit a form with:

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```